# How can I delete the same-named folders which are located in separate folders on the bash command line?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

First of all I want to explain what i would like to do:

I want to delete `node_modules` folders from each folder on the bash command line like that

```
.
└── Projects/
    ├── project-1/
    │   └── node_modules
    ├── project-2/
    │   └── node_modules
    └── project-3/
        └── node_modules
```

I tried this way  `~\Projects rm -r */node_modules`

Comment: Is `~\Projects` your shell prompt, or did you actually type that?

Comment: The parent directory should part of the pathname, you don't type it as a command. `rm -r Projects/*/node_modules`

Comment: Or you could do `cd Project` first, then type your `rm` command.

Comment: did you try this `rm -r Projects/*/node_modules`? It didn't work.

Comment: You need `-rf`, but be careful not to remove more than you want.

Comment: @choroba You only need `-f` if you want it to override permissions without prompting?

Comment: When it didn't work, what happened? Did you get an error?

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the advice. I had an error message as no such file or directory. I tried to add the -f flag but it didn't affect too.

Comment: Your current directory is the one labeled `.` in the diagram, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` to list down the directories recursively that you want and then execute rm -r on the result.

`find` command gives you the ability to do that in a single command.

```
find Projects/ -name "node_modules" -type d -exec rm -r {} \;
```

- find Projects/ -> Looks up inside the Projects folder.
- -name "node_modules" -> looks for files/directories "name_modules"
- -type d -> looks up only directories

You can refer the man page or lookup on the internet for using the find command for various other uses.